# Getting A ID Value Unique To An Instance Of An Ansible Playbook

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to create an external file that every single task (Python modules which I've implemented) in the playbook should read from and write into some information.

I wanted to use the process ID for the playbook itself but I'm not sure how to fetch this information from within the module itself i.e. the python script itself.

`$PPID` keeps changing with every task, as running the following playbook shows:

```yaml
---
# BEGINNING OF PLAY 1
- hosts: DHILIN1
  tasks:
   - name: "get pid of playbook ONCE"
     shell: echo "$PPID"
     register: ansible_pid

   - name: "print ansible_pid ONCE"
     debug: msg="{{ ansible_pid }}"

   - name: "Pause for 2 minutes"
     pause:
      minutes: 2
   
   - name: "get pid of playbook TWICE"
     shell: echo "$PPID"
     register: ansible_pid

   - name: "print ansible_pid TWICE"
     debug: msg="{{ ansible_pid }}"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PLAY [TESTVM] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [TESTVM]

TASK [get pid of playbook ONCE] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [TESTVM]

TASK [print ansible_pid ONCE] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [TESTVM] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "echo \"$PPID\"",
        "delta": "0:00:00.004504",
        "end": "2021-08-06 01:48:43.929258",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-08-06 01:48:43.924754",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "2850132",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "2850132"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Pause for 2 minutes] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Pausing for 120 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [TESTVM]

TASK [get pid of playbook TWICE] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [TESTVM]

TASK [print ansible_pid TWICE] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [TESTVM] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "echo \"$PPID\"",
        "delta": "0:00:00.004825",
        "end": "2021-08-06 01:50:44.831919",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-08-06 01:50:44.827094",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "2850343",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "2850343"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
TESTVM                    : ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see, the value for the `PPID` was

```
"stdout": "2850132"
"stdout": "2850343"
```

the 1st and 2nd times respectively.
Is there any value like a process ID or something similar that is

1. Unique to this instance of the playbook run ?
2. Accessible to the module's underlying python script ?
3. Without involving use of psutil or any package that doesn't come as part of Python 3.X

Comment: The playbook processes run on the controller and the tasks are running on the remote nodes. See [Controlling playbook execution: strategies and more](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#controlling-playbook-execution-strategies-and-more). Moreover, there is no shared filesystem among the controller and the remote nodes. See [Ansible module architecture](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#ansible-module-architecture). Your idea is not feasible.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka, if my current idea isn't feasible, I'm not very confident that my next idea is either, is there any way to share or access information about the host\playbook i.e. host facts or any playbook related info from custom Ansible Modules ?

Comment: Whatever you need in a module can be put into the arguments ``"to access ... host facts or any playbook-related info from custom Ansible Modules"``. See [Passing args](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#passing-args).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `PID` and `PPID`, as ansible will spawn a lot of different processes on the target hosts and by default uses new SSH connections for every task.
I don't think ansible has a unique id for each run, as it can't guarantee uniqueness and there are a lot of edge-cases with concurrent runs.

You will have to generate your own ID and safe it to a variable. You can then access the variable and do with the ID, whatever you like.

You can, for example, use the new [`random_string`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/random_string_lookup.html) lookup. That one was introduced in version 3.4.0 of the `community.general` collection, so you will need to have this version installed and you will need a relatively new version of ansible for it to be able to resolve fully-qualified names.

```yaml
- hosts: DHILIN1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        unique_id: "{{ lookup('community.general.random_string', upper=false, special=false) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ unique_id }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ unique_id }}"
```

The value of `unique_id` will be different on each run and each host, but it will stay the same during the whole run for a single host.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Create a file that every task in the playbook should read from and write into some information.**"*

A: Create a temporary file, .e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/create-tempfile.yml
---
- block:
    - file:
        state: directory
        path: /var/run/ansible-shared
        owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        group: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        mode: "0775"
      become: true
    - tempfile:
        path: /var/run/ansible-shared
      register: tempfile
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

and use this file to write the results, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat tasks/write-results.yml
---
- blockinfile:
    path: "{{ tempfile.path }}"
    marker: "# {{ task }} - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - {mark}"
    insertafter: EOF
    block: |-
      {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
      {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host]['result']['stdout'] }}
      {% endfor %}
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

Then import these tasks into a playbook, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: tasks/create-tempfile.yml

    - name: Task 1.
      command: date
      register: result
    - import_tasks: tasks/write-results.yml
      vars:
        task: Task 1

    - name: Task 2.
      command: date
      register: result
    - import_tasks: tasks/write-results.yml
      vars:
        task: Task 2

    - debug:
        msg: "Results stored in {{ tempfile.path }}"
      run_once: true
```

The results will be stored in this file, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat /var/run/ansible-shared/ansible.v0481lfk
# Task 1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - BEGIN
test_11 Fri Aug  6 08:58:45 UTC 2021
test_12 Fri Aug  6 08:58:45 UTC 2021
test_13 Fri Aug  6 08:58:46 UTC 2021
# Task 1 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - END
# Task 2 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - BEGIN
test_11 Fri Aug  6 08:58:48 UTC 2021
test_12 Fri Aug  6 08:58:48 UTC 2021
test_13 Fri Aug  6 08:58:48 UTC 2021
# Task 2 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - END
```

Fit the structures and the format to your needs.